# Calling method in Singleton instance from Hangfire backgroundjob C# Web Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, singleton, hangfire

As the title says I'm trying to call a method that resides within a Singleton instance from a backgroundjob in Hangfire. I have tried enqueuing the job using the code below but none of them work:

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<MyApplicatonContext>(x => x.TestString());
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => MyApplicatonContext.Instance.TestString());
```

My singleton class looks like this:

```
public sealed class MyApplicatonContext 
{
    // Singleton instance
    private readonly static Lazy<MyApplicatonContext> _instance = new Lazy<MyApplicatonContext>(() => new MyApplicatonContext(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyApplicatonHub>().Clients));

    private readonly string _testString = "It works!";

    private IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> Clients
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private MyApplicatonContext (IHubConnectionContext<dynamic> clients)
    {
        Clients = clients;
    }

    public static MyApplicatonContext Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }

    public string TestString()
    {
        return _testString;
    }
}
```

Hangfire then generates this job and error:

```
using MyApplicaton.Context;

MyApplicatonContext context = Activate<MyApplicatonContext>(); 
context.TestString();
```

> System.InvalidOperationException
>
> The type `MyApplicaton.Context.MyApplicatonContext` does not contain a method
>   with signature `TestString()`
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The type
>   `MyApplicaton.Context.MyApplicatonContext` does not contain a method with
>   signature `TestString()`    at
>   Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.Deserialize()

How can I get this to work?

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it seems like a lot of extra hassle, but you should probably consider using an IoC container to manage the lifecycle of `MyApplicationContext` and then hook into that - see [information on using IoC Containers with hangfire](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html).

At a push, you could implement your own [`JobActivator`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/JobActivator.cs) class (again, the instructions are in the [IoC Docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html)), but I'd strongly advise investigating the IoC Container route first.